# Windows Azure Web Sites - how are they configured?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

With the new WAWS service, you can create default installs of apps like Wordpress and DotNetNuke. These apps typically use local storage within the web app dir to hold uploaded content files (images, etc.), but WAWS allows you to easily scale to multiple instances. How are these content directories managed? Is there any published information on this?

Comment: As far as I know you have a 1GB free space, this doesn't answer your question directly but provides more information on the area of storage: http://www.bradygaster.com/windows-azure-web-sites-log-cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a session at TechEd North America and Europe about [how Windows Azure Web Sites works under the hood](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2012/AZR305).

To briefly summarize:

Storage is provided via Windows Azure Drive (aka XDrive; a component of Windows Azure Storage which is seated in a Page Blob)

Instances share this resource through some "secret sauce" which is proprietary to the Windows Azure Web Sites team.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I've read in other places that web site files aren't synchronized between instances, but this directly contradicts that claim. Because the files are stored in one durable place and accessed via shared storage, that is a non-issue.

Comment: We had Nir on WebCampsTV to talk about the same content and we actually got him to expand on some explainations and answer some common questions from SO. You can view this on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Internals-with-Nir-Mashkowski)